# C# How To Simulate Ruzzle Gestures

Tags: c#, events

I am trying to re-create the populare smartphone game " Ruzzle " for windows with C#.
I am stuck trying to figure out **what c# event could simulate the ruzzle gestures.**
If you are not familiar with the game , here is a short video. Jump at minute 1:13
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uUk3_4vduo

**I have created a "Check" class like this:**

```
public partial class Check: UserControl
    {
        public Check()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string _letter; //letter contained  in the check

        public string Letter
        {
            get { return _letter; }
            set { _letter = value; }
        }
        int _value; //value of the letter

        public int Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value= value; }
        }

        bool _selected; //if true orange background else white background

        public bool Selected
        {
            get { return _selected; }
            set { _selected= value; }
        }
        public Check(string l)
        {
            this._letter = l.ToUpper();
            this._selected = false;
            this.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Check_Paint);
        }

        void Check_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle area = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(Height-3, Width-3));
            if (!Selezionato)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(Height, Width)));
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, area);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this._letter, DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(Height / 3, Width /3));
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this._value.ToString(), DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(Height-15, Width-15));
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, area);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, area);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this._letter, DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(Height / 3, Width ));
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this._value.ToString(), DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(Height, Width));
            }
        }
```

Than I have a class "Game" that manages the bi-dimensional array of "Check"

```
class Game
    {
        Scacco[,] myGame;

        public Game(Control father)
        {
            myGame= new Check[4, 4];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    myGame[i, j] = new Check("l");
                    myGame[i, j].Location = new Point((i * (myGame[i, j].Width) + 10), (j * (myGame[i, j].Height )+ 10));

                    father.Controls.Add(myGame[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here I need to figure out if there is an event like " while mouse is down " . I know the mousedown events exists but it only works on one Check: as soon as I hover the mouse on another check the event fails to recognize that my mouse is still down.**

Let me know if my explanation is clear or not.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using polling for mouse location could track a path over the squares the user visited. Maybe that would work.

Answer (score 0):

The `MouseMove` event will be generated while the mouse is down, but only to the Win32 window which originally captured the mouse.  If capture isn't used, the messages go to the window under the mouse.

Of course to distinguish "movement with the mouse button down" from "movement with all mouse buttons released" you can set a flag in the `MouseDown` event.